# gRPC with synchronous calls in node application

Tags: node.js, grpc

I have an application which implements multiple gRPC servers.
The client side is implemented in nodeJS.
The client invokes multiple gRPC calls one after another.
Since in nodeJS, channel is created per ServiceClient , how to ensure that the first gRPC call is complete before the second gRPC call is invoked.

Is there a way to specify multiple ServiceClient to use same channel for all the communication ?

Is there a way to use synchronous gRPC calls in nodeJS ?

Answer (score 1):

Node gRPC does not have synchronous calls. As with any asynchronous Node operation, you can ensure that two calls are made sequentially by invoking the second one in the completion callback of the first.

And no, there is not currently an API to have multiple client objects use the same channel.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question is quite old, answered just in case someone still needs it in the future.

YES, call the second gRPC after the end event. Below is the client example.

```js
const target = "localhost:50055";
const client = new proto.APINAME(target, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

const call = client.APIMETHOD(metadata);

call.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
call.on("end", function() {
  // call the second gRPC
});
```