# How to correctly handle callbacks between Node.js gRPC client & server

Tags: node.js, express, grpc

I have a simple Express/ gRPC project that's supposed to print a hard coded JSON object to the browser & console. The problem is that the object isn't returned to the client in time to receive it from the gRPC server.

My project is actually a modification of [this Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-grpc/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) project. I've only implemented the `listBooks` method though, and have changed Go to Express. I was able to successfully get a response from the server in the Codelabs project.

At first I thought about avoiding callbacks, and trying promises (promises, promisfy...) instead. But I haven't had success. Also, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318298/grpc-with-synchronous-calls-in-node-application) answer, I now know that Node gRPC isn't implemented to have sync:

> "Node gRPC does not have synchronous calls." - murgatroid99

With that said, the output is showing that the data isn't being received. What do I need to do to have the client wait for the data to be available to be received?

**products.proto**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package products;

service ProductService {
  rpc ListProduct (Empty) returns (ProductList) {}
}

message Empty {}

message Product {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string price = 3;
}

message ProductList {
  repeated Product products = 1;
}
```

**server.js**

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/products.proto';
var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    });
var productsProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).products;


var products = [{
    id: 123,
    name: 'apple',
    price: '$2'
}];


 function listProduct(call, callback){
     console.log(products);
     callback(null, products);
 }


function main(){
    var server = new grpc.Server();

    server.addService(productsProto.ProductService.service, 
        {ListProduct: listProduct}
    );

    server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
    console.log("server started");
    server.start();
}

main();
```

**client.js**

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/products.proto';
var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    });

var products = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).products;
var client = new products.ProductService('localhost:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());


function printResponse(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
    else{
        console.log(response);
    }
}

function listProducts() {   
    client.listProduct({}, function(error, products){
         printResponse(error, products);
    });
}


exports.listProducts = listProducts;
```

**client-server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var client = require('./client');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Hello World!');
    client.listProducts();
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () =>
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'),
);
```

### Actual Result

The gRPC server obviously already has the object, but I print it to console just for fun. The client prints its callback result to the console, but is only printing an empty object.

**server.js Output**

```
[ { id: 123, name: 'apple', price: '$2' } ]
```

**client.js Output**

```
Hello World!
{ products: [] }
```

### To Reproduce

1. Open 2 terminals, `cd` to project
2. Run `node server.js` in one terminal
3. Run `node client-server.js` in the other terminal
4. Open a browser to `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with synchronous vs asynchronous actions.

The object you are trying to send from your server request handler does not match the response message type you declared in your `products.proto` file. The response message type `ProductList` is a message with a single field `products` that is a repeated list of `ProductObjects`. So to match that the object you send should be an object with a `products` field that contains an array of objects structured like `ProductObject` messages. The code you have is almost there. You have the array, so your server handler code should look like this:

```js
function listProduct(call, callback){
    console.log(products);
    callback(null, {products: products});
}
```

The output you already have hints towards this. The object your client receives is `{products: []}`, which is the structure of the objects your server should be sending.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. You don't know how long I've been working with this problem.